# Do not validate field when DIV is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I use the **Parsley** plugin to validate my fields, however I have a few:

```
<select title="Minute" name="minute" id="minute" multiple="multiple" data-parsley-required data-parsley-error-message="is mandatory" onChange="show_value();" class="selectpicker cronbox form-control >
<option value="*">*</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

Which I can only validate when I enable them by a control DIV

I valid them well

`Data-parsley-required data-parsley-error-message = "is mandatory"`

How can I not validate these fields when my `DIV` is `style = "display: none"`?

Answer (score 0):

As well as hiding the div you could always add 'disabled' this will prevent posting and might fix your problem.

```
<select disabled title="Minute" name="minute" id="minute" multiple="multiple" data-parsley-required data-parsley-error-message="is mandatory" onChange="show_value();" class="selectpicker cronbox form-control >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:hidden` to the `excluded` option. Consider adding a `disabled` attribute and adding `[disabled]` to the `excluded` option.